# Is there any way to emulate Javascript Intrinsic Objects in C#

Tags: c#

In JavaScript, I can call a function like so:

```
x = myFunction({"meetingID": 2, "meetingRoom": "A103"});
```

myFunction() then receives an object which I can parse with JSON, or just by referencing the object's properties:

```
function myFunction( args ) {
    var x = args.meetingID;
}
```

Is there any such similar construct in C#?  Are there such things as "inline objects", or "on the fly objects"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) in conjunction with [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword.

```
void MyFunction(dynamic args)
{
    var x = args.MeetingId;
}

MyFunction(new { MeetingId = 2, MeetingRoom = "A103" });
```

Beware - this works different from javascript. If object passed to `MyFunction` doesn't contain property `MeetingId`, you'll get exception at runtime.

Comment: Oh, wow!  That's almost identical to the js treatment.  Will make a very easy transition for me.  It just needs the "new" keyword in front of the object {}. ;-)  EDIT: Frankly, I like it BETTER than the js way of ("label": value).

Comment: Just note that this is noticeably slow at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary

```
public static void Main()
{
    myFunction(new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "meetingID", 2},
            { "meetingRoom", "A103"}
        }
    );
}

public static void myFunction(Dictionary<string,object> args)
{
    var x = args["meetingID"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small suggestion .. if possible, it will be safer to use optional parameters instead:

```
string myFunction( int meetingID = 0, string meetingRoom = null ) { 
    var x = meetingID;
}
```

then you can use it like :

```
var x = myFunction( meetingID: 2, meetingRoom: "A103" );
var y = myFunction( meetingRoom:"A103" ); // order doesn't matter if you specify the parameter name
var z = myFunction( 3, "B109" );
var _ = myFunction();
```